# How to access another version of uploaded image

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

**CONTROLLER**

```
def get_profile_pic(id)
  @current_user = User.find(id)
end
```

**VIEW**

```
<%= image_tag(get_profile_pic(session[:user_id]).profile_pic_url) if    get_profile_pic(session[:user_id]).profile_pic? %>
```

this gives me original image path, i have thumb version and I want that.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its easy. I have a catalogue with carrierwave uploader as image. In your case profile_pic.

```
# original
catalogue.image_url

# thumb
catalogue.image.thumb.url

# large
catalogue.image.large.url
```

same applies to your profile_pic uploader; 'large', 'thumb' or any other size you are generating.

Also just check if the file exists at that url in controller itself and return the url from controller method 'get_profile_pic' and in view just show no image when profile pic absent else show the uploaded profile pic

Comment: thank you for your feedback but unfortunately this is giving me the same original image  

   def get_profile_pic(id)
      current_user = User.find(id)
      
      # original
      test = current_user.profile_pic.url

      # thumb
      #test = current_user.profile_pic.thumb.url
   end

Comment: can you paste the relevant carrierwave uploader file code where you generate the thumbnail of the original file? It should work. I tested the code before if posted the reply.

Comment: here is code snippet else are default generated by gem
  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fit => [128, 128]
  end

Comment: try this catalogue.image_url(:thumb) Also restart your rails server once and upload a profile pic to a new user and check if it works.

Comment: Hey @Aditya thanks this line of code work for me 
@ test = current_user.profile_pic.thumb.url

Thank a lot :)